# Не выводит на экран данные из поисковой строки в PHP

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Помогите пожалуйста! Не могу понять почему данные не выводятся на экран! PhpDesigner 8 не видит синтактической ошибки, да и браузер то же ошибки не выдает, но результат поиска не хочет  все равно выдавать не хочет. Что делать?

Вот html форма:

```
<html>
  <head>
 <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="search" action="index.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="words"/>
 <input type="submit" name="bsearch" value="поиск"/>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Вот index.php форма:

```
<?php
function search($words){
     $words =htmlspecialchars($words);
     if ($words === '') return false;
     $query_search = '';

     $arraywords = explode(' ', $words);
     foreach($arraywords as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($arraywords[$key - 1]))
            $query_search .= ' OR';
            $query_search .= ' description LIKE "%'.$value.'%" OR title LIKE "%'.$value.'%"';  
     }
     $query = "SELECT * FROM riskyjobs WHERE $query_search";
     $dbc = mysqli_connect ('localhost', '', '', '')
     or die ('ошибка соединения с MySQL-сервером'); 
     $result_set = $dbc->query($query);
     mysqli_close($dbc);

     $i = 0;
     while($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) {
         $results[$i] = $row;
         $i++;
     }
     return $results;
}


if (isset($_POST['bsearch'])) {
    $words = $_POST['words'];
    $results = search($words);
    print_r($results);
} 
?>
```

Comment: Вы используете процедурный стиль mysqli. а тут $dbc->query($query); - объектный. Используйте какой-то один

Comment: Все равно не получается! Хоть я и поменял  $mysqli = new mysqli, $result_set = $mysqli->query($query);
     $mysqli->close(); Все равно запрос отправляется как будто в пустоту!